# Generate random number again if it doesn't equal x

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a number between 1 and 100, but I want it to keep regenerating that number until it equals 50, once it equals 50, then echo it out. How would I do this?

My Function:

```
function create() {
    $production_line = mt_rand(0, 3);
    $random1 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $random2 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $random3 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $random4 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $random5 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $random6 = mt_rand(0, 9);
    $production_year = mt_rand(3, 4);
    $week1 = 4;
    $week2 = 8;
    $factory1 = 4;
    $factory2 = 8;

    if ($production_line + $random1 + $random2 + $random3 + $random4 + $random5 + $random6 + $production_year + $week1 + $week2 + $factory1 + $factory2 == 55) {
        return $production_line.$random1.$random2.$random3.$random4.$random5.$random6.$production_year.$week1.$week2.$factory1.$factory2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop, what's the problem? But what's the point? Just print 50.

Comment: I just used example numbers, the amount of numbers it can really produce are way too big

Comment: i dont know whats the use to generate the random nu. and check agains the fix variable.. it could be a performance issue and time wasted thats it..  cn you pls explain ur real need??

Comment: I love these homeworks

Comment: @Barmar, That was a great point ;)

Comment: I edited the original question with the formula, I need help creating it, and it's not homework lol

Comment: Run it in a while loop. Again, what's the problem?

Comment: When I run it in a while loop, the page never loads, and when it does (after some 30 mins or so), it has a nested limit error, when I increase it to 1000, it still gives it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate and test all the random numbers inside a `while` loop.

```
function create() {
    $week1 = 4;
    $week2 = 8;
    $factory1 = 4;
    $factory2 = 8;
    while (true) {
        $production_line = mt_rand(0, 3);
        $random1 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $random2 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $random3 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $random4 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $random5 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $random6 = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $production_year = mt_rand(3, 4);

        if ($production_line + $random1 + $random2 + $random3 + $random4 + $random5 + $random6 + $production_year + $week1 + $week2 + $factory1 + $factory2 == 55) {
            return $production_line.$random1.$random2.$random3.$random4.$random5.$random6.$production_year.$week1.$week2.$factory1.$factory2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks, is there any way to speed it up? If not it's okay. This isn't used for production purposes. Only learning purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Use a simple loop:

```
$i = 0;
while ($rand = mt_rand(0,100)) {
    $i++;
    if ($rand == 50) {
        // found 50, so break out of the loop
        break;
    }
}

echo "It took $i iterations to find 50";
```

But that's a bit pointless, right? If you're just going to output `50` all the time, then why do you need to generate a random number? Just echo `50` instead. Also note that this could be a slow operation if the larger limit is a bigger number.

Comment: In addition, you will probably want to keep a counter. While remote, there are chances you'll be doing several thousand iterations before you hit that "random" 50. Not very nice for the server.

Comment: Useful, but I would abort the loop if a thousand iterations hasn't resulted in 50.

Comment: @MueR: That's *highly* unlikely. As already mentioned in the answer, this could get really slow for larger numbers, so I don't really recommend doing this. It's possible to abort, but this was just a pointer for the OP on how to proceed.

Comment: I agree the chances are remote, but with random number generation, you never know. Better safe than sorry, especially when it incurs the wrath of your local server administrator :P

Answer (score 3):

I've rearranged bits of the code to make it more cohesive:

```
function create() {
    do {
        $arr = [
            mt_rand(0, 3), // line
            mt_rand(0, 9), 
            mt_rand(0, 9),
            mt_rand(0, 9),
            mt_rand(0, 9),
            mt_rand(0, 9),
            mt_rand(0, 9),
            mt_rand(3, 4), // year
            4, // weeks
            8,
            4, // factories
            8,
        ];
    } while (array_sum($arr) != 55);

    return join('', $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 0;
$try = 0;

while ($number != 50) {
  $try++;
  $number = rand(1,100);
}

echo "found $number after $try cycles";
```