# A random number is generated , generate it again if it does not match a condition. How to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Newbie currently taking an online python course.

```
    # Generate Number 1
from random import choices
population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
weights = [0.11, 0.10, 0.14, 0.09, 0.13, 0.03, 0.08, 0.07, 0.09, 0.02, 0.03]
number1 = choices(population, weights)


# Generate Number 2
population2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
weights2 = [0.03, 0.07, 0.05, 0.05, 0.09, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.04]
number2 = choices(population2, weights2)

if number1[0] + 1 < number2[0] < number1[0] + 12 :
    print(number1 + number2)
else :
```

I was able to generate 2 random numbers with their respective weights with the help of some posts here on this website.

If the condition on the `if` statement is not true i want to tell the program to keep generating number 2 again until such condition is met. My problem is that i don't know what to look for to study.

Could someone please provide me a hint for what i have to study? Such as *" look into `For` loops or into `x` python function"*. I hope i can study and figure it out by myself rather than having someone tell me what to do directly.

would this post be of aid in my case?

[Generate random number again if it doesn't equal x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126816/generate-random-number-again-if-it-doesnt-equal-x)

using 2020.3 Community Edition PyCharm

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: The other question is PHP, but the basic logic should be the same.

Comment: You are trying to generate two random numbers, match the condition, and if condition doesn't match , regenerating both the numbers. Instead, better way will be to generate one number, and generate second number from the sub-set of the numbers which satisfy your condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say one way to learn is to get a code you have no clue what it does, excepted that the output is what you want, and so you try to break it part by part to understand what that means.

Maybe after you can read. But reading about things you don't know is often not efficient.

So I am not explaining my answer, in line with what I've just written ;)

```
from random import choices

population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
weights = [0.11, 0.10, 0.14, 0.09, 0.13, 0.03, 0.08, 0.07, 0.09, 0.02, 0.03]

population2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
weights2 = [0.03, 0.07, 0.05, 0.05, 0.09, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.04]

while True:
    number1 = choices(population, weights)
    number2 = choices(population2, weights2)

    if number1[0] + 1 < number2[0] < number1[0] + 12 :
        print (number1 + number2)
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! Will definitely look into the while function.

Comment: If that helps, think about accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

one way is you could add `while` loop in `else`

```py
    # Generate Number 1
from random import choices
population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
weights = [0.11, 0.10, 0.14, 0.09, 0.13, 0.03, 0.08, 0.07, 0.09, 0.02, 0.03]
number1 = choices(population, weights)


# Generate Number 2
population2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
weights2 = [0.03, 0.07, 0.05, 0.05, 0.09, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.04]
number2 = choices(population2, weights2)

if number1[0] + 1 < number2[0] < number1[0] + 12 :
    print(number1 + number2)
else :
    while(!(number1[0] + 1 < number2[0] < number1[0] + 12)):
        number2 = choices(population2, weights2)
```

but the problem is that condition inside `while` should satisfy for some value otherwise it would go in infinite loop.